# can't set simulated metric to change

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a UIViewController segued to from a UITableViewController which is itself embedded in a UINavigationController.

In the Attributes pane of the Utilities inspector, I have set Top Bar to Translucent Black Navigation Bar (under Simulated Metrics).

That works all fine and dandy in the UITableViewController but my view in the UIViewController was sliding back up behind the Navigation Bar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091971/problem-when-set-navigationbar-to-black-translucent-style) so I thought I'd try to change the default for Utilities inspector > Attributes pane > Simulated Metrics > Top Bar to Black Navigation Bar.

Didn't work.  It seems like I can't UN-infer any of the Simulated Metrics.

Answer (score 5):

Just to check your understanding... Simulated Metrics are just how the status bar/tab bar etc appear in Interface Builder. These don't affect the running app.

The easiest place to change your status bar type is in your target's info.plist:

[image]

To change it programmatically, just use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

To change the nav bar style

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Comment: Ooooh, I kinda get it.  They don't affect the running app.  But they do affect the running app when I set them for the UINavigationController.

Comment: More specifically, then how does one change Top Bar/Nav Bar behavior?

Comment: Nope, the simulated metrics are just that... simulated. I guess the style you chose is the current default style.. If you set it in the info.plist, it sets it for the whole app. I add how to change it programmatically to my answer.

Comment: Dunno about that - I can change the Top Bar by changing the Simulated Metric for the initial UINavigationController.

Comment: @Ashley, I agree with you, I have wasted all my day, searching, that why Status bar behaviours, could not be changed via Interface Builder. You have given the answer in first line. That is a very good information you shared. But, I want to know that from where you got to know  about this info. (Simulated metrics are only for IB, they not affect the running app.)